# Find the min and max values from one column associated with a particular id from another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, nested

Hi (im pretty new to SQl), I want to find the min and max caseno associated with the id and also be able to get the price associated with those caseno. My data from two tables looks like this:

table 1

```
Id |Caseno |Price 
-----------------
10 |101    |5
10 |102    |6
10 |103    |7
11 |201    |5
11 |202    |6
12 |203    |5
12 |204    |6
12 |205    |7
```

table 2

```
Caseno  |Price 
----------------
101     |5
102     |6
103     |7
201     |5
202     |6 
203     |5
204     |6
205     |7
```

i want my output to be the following:

```
Id |Caseno|Price
-----------------
10 |101   | 5
10 |103   | 7
11 |201   | 5
12 |203   | 5
12 |205   | 7
```

the query i used is below but its not giving me the right output:

```
select id, price, max(caseno) lowestcaseno ,min(caseno) highestcaseno
from table1 t join table2 a on (t.caseno=a.caseno)
group by id,price
```

Do i need to create sub-queries? if yes should i put them in from or where clause? Thank you and any help is much appreciated!

Comment: what database engine and version are you using?

Comment: Why do you have two so similar tables? (That's the main issue.)

Comment: Why does id `11` only appear once in the result set?

Comment: im using SQL Server Database Engine.

Comment: my main requirement would be to get the lowest and the highest case number associated with the id

Comment: what happen if the `MIN` is equal to `MAX`? want duplicate row or just one?

Comment: And what version of SQL?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I think this is one instance where having the min and max be the same might not be a deal-breaker.  Most likely, if he were using such a result set as a report he would want to show both values for each casino, even if they were the same.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I add another column to show that case more clear, just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample data has some issues, but most of it would seem to imply that you want to retain casinos having the maximum and minimum price for each `Id` group.  If so, then one approach is to create a subquery to identify these casinos, and then use this subquery to select the correct full records in your original table.

```
SELECT c1.Id,
       c1.Caseno,
       c1.Price
FROM caseno c1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Id,
           MIN(Price) AS minPrice,
           MAX(Price) AS maxPrice
    FROM caseno
    GROUP BY Id
) c2
    ON c1.Id = c2.Id AND
       (c1.Price = c2.minPrice OR
        c1.Price = c2.maxPrice)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a query as ,

```
select t1.ID, t1.Caseno, t1.Price from table1 t1
where price = (select min(price) from table1 t2 where t1.Caseno =t2.Caseno )
or price = (select min(price) from table1 t2 where t1.Caseno =t2.Caseno )
order by price
```

Hope you got it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Id, Caseno, Price, 
       CASE WHEN rn_minPrice = rn_maxPrice THEN 'MIN/MAX'
            WHEN rn_minPrice = 1           THEN 'MIN'
            ELSE 'MAX'
       END result
FROM (
        SELECT Id,
               Caseno,
               Price 
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Price )      AS rn_minPrice,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Price DESC ) AS rn_maxPrice,
        FROM table1
     ) as T
WHERE rn_minPrice = 1 or rn_maxPrice = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Table1 as t1. I don't think there is any use of table 2 as Caseno,Price column also exists in table1.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT ID,MIN(PRICE) PRICE FROM T1 GROUP BY ID
   UNION
   SELECT ID,MAX(PRICE) FROM T1 GROUP BY ID
)
SELECT C.ID,T1.CASENO,C.PRICE FROM CTE C 
INNER JOIN T1 ON C.ID=T1.ID AND C.PRICE=T1.PRICE  ORDER BY C.ID
```